# Azure PostgreSQL: it is not possible to remove database through Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-database-postgresql

I have created pipeline using Azure DevOps for Azure PostgreSQL database.

What actually pipeline do?

1. Connect to PostgreSQL;
2. Remove database db_test from PostgreSQL using Azure CLI;

> az postgres db delete -g my_group -s database_here -n db_test --yes

However, I cannot do this due to error:

```
An unexpected error occured while processing the request.
```

Then, I was trying to remove the database using psql, but with no luck due to existing connections to database.

From my point of view - Azure CLI must handle such issues and remove database or pass correct error message to me. For example it would be great if parameter --force will be implemented.

I have removed all connections to database using the following syntax in a bash script:

```
psql "host=database_here port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres@database_here password=ReallyStrongPassword sslmode=require" -c "REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db_test FROM PUBLIC; SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'db_test';"
```

and added DROP database action additionally to my pipeline:

```
psql "host=database_here port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres@database_here password=ReallyStrongPassword sslmode=require" -c "DROP database db_test;"
```

But I didn't remove AZ CLI database removal step from pipeline and it has failed with the following output:

```
Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed
```

I think on this step, AZ CLI should return something like: "Database does not exist." just as informative message.

How to properly handle such situations on the Azure side?

Answer (score 2):

Does `az postgres db show` show the database details? Please check if this is happening due to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7285#issuecomment-420717903) behaviour, albeit the discussion in the quoted thread is in context with a SQL database.

If the issue still persists, please feel free to drop your feedback [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/postgres/db?view=azure-cli-latest#feedback) open an issue with our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) for our internal Team to take a look at.

Thanks for the feedback!