# Azure DevOps: How to save KV variable into the common variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline in Azure DevOps do the following:

[image]

1. Bash script: to avoid problem that database cannot be removed( [Azure PostgreSQL: it is not possible to remove database through Azure CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268141/azure-postgresql-it-is-not-possible-to-remove-database-through-azure-cli) )
2. Azure Key Vault: Obtain Key Vault variables for login to PostgreSQL database
3. Azure CLI: Remove database using Azure CLI;
4. NPM install: initialize NodeJS packages from package.json
5. NPM run: start apply.js file which connects to PostgreSQL, create database, and apply schema using liquibase;

apply.js uses some environment variables like `DB_HOST,DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER,` which are stored in Variable Group, however, the password in Key Vault is stored as `postgres-password` variable. So, the problem is how to save KV `postgres-admin-password` variable into common `DB_PASSWORD` variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a PowerShell inline task that set the `DB_PASSWORD` value like the `postgres-admin-password`:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DB_PASSWORD;]$(postgres-admin-password)"
```

Comment: Thank you Shayki for your help, it's exactly what I wanted.